# Pandas date based grouping to return rows on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has data like

```
1. id       date                   remarks
2. 1       12-01-2015 12:00:15     Good
3. 2       12-01-2015 1:00:14      OK
4. 1       13-01-2015 12:00:15     Not Ok
5. 2       14-01-2015 1:00:15      Bad
6. 3       15-01-2015 1:00:15      Good
```

I need the output in such a way that for each id the highest date and remarks is returned, so for id 2 it would return 14-01-2015 1:00:15 and remark as bad

Comment: please read, [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3):

I hope your date column is in dayfirst format if thats so,you need `groupby` on `id` with `idxmax` on `date` and reuse then from `loc` lookup. If its not in `dayfirst` format then `idxmin()` will help

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['date'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
    id                date remarks
2   1 2015-01-13 12:00:15  Not Ok
3   2 2015-01-14 01:00:15     Bad
4   3 2015-01-15 01:00:15    Good
```

If you dont want the index and intend to create a new dataframe with new index then (Thanks @Zero)

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['date'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=T‌​rue)
```

Comment: Good part here, it gives you original index, incase you don't need `df.loc[df.groupby('id')['date'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Better mention how your date was parsed, because that influences the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.sort_values('date').groupby('id', as_index=False).last()
print (df1)
   id                date remarks
0   1 2015-01-13 12:00:15  Not Ok
1   2 2015-01-14 01:00:15     Bad
2   3 2015-01-15 01:00:15    Good
```

Comment: I think your date was parsed incorrectly, since you're getting OK for id2 instead of Bad.